# C Error:expected unqualified-id before '[' token

Tags: c++

I want to write a program that can get the number of each different characters in a sentence.But when I use gcc to compile my code,it shows errors like this:
**error::expected unqualified-id before '[' token.** And these errors happen in these lines:

```
    CountMachine[cnt].ch=*(S.ch);
     CountMachine[cnt].count++;      
    if(*(S.ch)==CountMachine[j].ch)

.....
(where I use CountMachine[]).
```

Here is my complete code:

**CountChar.h:**

```
typedef struct 
{
    char ch;
    int count=0;
}CountMachine[50];

typedef struct
{
    char *ch;
    int length;
}HString;
```

**CountChar.cpp(but I use C's syntax)**

```
void CountChar(HString S)
{
    int cnt=0;
    for(int i=0;i<S.length;i++)
    {
        if(i==0)
        {
            CountMachine[cnt].ch=*(S.ch);
            CountMachine[cnt].count++;
            cnt++;
            S.ch++;
        }
        else
        {
            for(int j=0;j<cnt;j++)
            {
                if(*(S.ch)==CountMachine[j].ch)
                {
                    CountMachine[j].count++;
                    S.ch++;
                    break;
                }
                if(j==cnt-1)
                {
                    CountMachine[cnt].ch=*(S.ch);
                    CountMachine[cnt].count++;
                    cnt++;
                    S.ch++;
                }
            }

        }

    }
    printf("There are %d different characters.\n",cnt-1);
    for(int m=0;m<cnt-1;m++)
    {
        printf("the number of character %c is %d",CountMachine[m].ch,CountMachine[m].count);
    }
}
```

Comment: `CountMachine` is type name by typedef.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie That is valid in C. But part of `int count=0;` is invalid in C.

Comment: There is no "C syntax in C++". C and C++ are different languages. Identical syntax can have different semantics (and, as pointed out), this is not valid C anyway) Don't spam tags.

Comment: @Olaf I mean I use C syntax and  just compile my code in C++ environment.Does this work out? I do this for a long time:I program in C , save it as .cpp file and use gcc to compile it. So far,all my codes have run correctly(except this one).

Comment: @JiamingHuang: This is a very bad idea - to be polite! Learn C and C++ to see the differences. A simple example: try `static const int i = 10, a[i];` in both languages. Alternatively `auto int i = 10, a[i];` (in a block).

Comment: @JiamingHuang For an even simpler demonstration of the fact that C and C++ are different, try defining a variable named `class`. It's legal in C, but not in C++.

Comment: @Olaf Thanks for your explanation.I do know there are lots of differences between C and C++. But I just use g++ to compile my code which is programmed in C and my professor and TA told me it is OK to do this.

Comment: You may cite me in front of your teachers: They should learn the languages before spreading such nonsense. It might have been correct in the 1980ies(early 90ies where C++ was not standardised and C was at K&R resp. ANSI-C (C89/90). It has become dangerous advice with C99/C++98, but since 6 years, everyone teaching this should be instantly fired. If I ever saw one of my project members doing this, he had a serious talk to stop this and be kicked otherwise.

Comment: @JiamingHuang Your teachers are flat-out wrong. If possible, leave that class immediately; if not, keep your head down, do the work, and get out of there ASAP. Teach yourself C instead, because that class is useless. Worse, even; it's actively teaching you wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have a very fancy type alias that declares a `CountMachine` type, not a variable that contains an array of 50 unnamed structs.

```
typedef struct 
{
    char ch;
    int count=0;
}CountMachine[50];
//  CountMachine is a type (array 50 of unnamed struct)

// step-by step declaration is much more clear:

struct machine
{
    char ch;
    int count=0;
};

typedef struct machine machine_t;

machine_t machines[50];
// machines is a variable that holds an array of 50 machine_t
```

Comment: Worth noting types ending in `_t` are reserved for use by... POSIX, I think it was.

Answer (score 0):

You declare `CountMachine` as a type which includes 50 structures containing a character and an integer in `CountChar.h` and then you address the type itself in `CountChar.cpp`.

You cannot address a specific item in a type, you need to either create a variable of type `CountMachine` or remove the keyword `typedef` from the declaration of `CountMachine` in the header.